# div containing font is aligned if there's a background image, otherwise it goes out of boundaries

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a transparent div at the bottom of a button that has an image background.  This div will contain text that should be aligned.  The text varies in length, so the div should grow to accommodate the text.

My approach isn't working -- it's producing this result:

[image]

These buttons have the same classes; the only difference is that the one without an image is created dynamically:

```
        <button class="tiles" style="padding: 0px; background: url(../static/bilder/Multifunktionstür.jpg); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat" v-if="selectedCategory==''" >
             <div class="button-label flex-container">
                 <h3>MULTIFUNKTIONSTÜREN</h3>
             </div>
        </button>               
        <button v-for="category in categories" class="tiles" v-if="selectedCategory==''" @click="selectCategory(category)">
            <div class="button-label  flex-container">
            <h3>{{ category.name.toUpperCase() }}</h3>
            </div>

        </button>



 .flex-container {
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -moz-box;
     display: -ms-flexbox;
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;


 }

 .button-label {
     text-align: center;
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 20%;
     bottom: 0px;
 }
```

Any ideas as to what I could be doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Is the div still too white or anything? Do you want the background removed? Than you should change your`.button-label` property to `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);`

Comment: it will help if you can provide a working prototype on codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are giving inline style the div with the image : style="padding: 0px;". This is removing the space in the block with the image. If you apply padding 0 to the other box also, you should be able to achieve the same results in both boxes.

You can use:

```
.button.tiles {
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add left 0px and check

```
`.button-label {
     text-align: center;
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 20%;
     bottom: 0px;
     left:0px;
 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

For the most consistent and reliable `absolute` positioning adjust the following styles accordingly:

```
.button-label {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: auto;
}
```